# Forming syndrome bit stream for Berlekamp-Massey BCH decoding

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

I'm implementing a (127, 64, 10) BCH decoder using the [Berlekamp-Massey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm#The_algorithm_for_the_binary_field) algorithm and I'm not able to figure out how to provide the syndromes to the algorithm. My syndrome calculation logic computes 2t integers (where each integer represents a polynomial), but the algorithm on Wiki expects a bit string of length N as an input.
How are the 2t polynomials converted to an N-bit stream? Am I expected to convert the 2t integers to one long bit string of N bits and then provide it to the algorithm?

Comment: The syndromes are the values of the protected message polynomial evaluated at the powers of the field cardinal. When they are all zeroes, the protected message is error-free.

Note that the syndromes are computed independently of any encoder.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, my syndromes are obtained using the received code and some GF(2^7) arithmetic. I'm not able to figure out how to represent the syndromes in a way that the BM algorithm expects to compute the correct error locator polynomial.